# See docker container logs on host while using gelf driver

Tags: docker, logging, syslog, rsyslog, graylog2

I am using gelf as log driver for my docker container. In log options i provided udp endpoint.

Now when i start the container, everything is working as expected.

My question is, if it is possible to see the container logs in the host where it is running(not at UDP endpoint)?

Comment: do you mean to see container logs as "docker logs ..." ?

Comment: @Hazim *docker logs* won't work for logging drivers that do not send logs to [commands output](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/). To answer the question, no, it's not possible to see the logs in any other place than their destination

Comment: @Hazim I am looking for anyway to see logs in host, I know that it is not possible to see the logs from docker logs when we change the log-driver. But is there any other way?

Comment: No recommended way of doing that. I did add a workaround in my answer but it is a "workaround", not sure if it is suitable for your need

Answer (score 2):

This depends on Docker version.

Docker 20.10 and up introduces “dual logging”, which uses a local buffer that allows you to use the docker logs command for any logging driver.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about seeing the logs via `docker logs` command on the machine running the docker containers, its not possible to do so when using other logging drivers.

See [limitations of logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#limitations-of-logging-drivers).

If you know where the log is at inside the container, a work around would be to write a script which copies the log file from the container and displays it, or maybe just `exec`'s into the container and displays it. But I really wouldn't recommend that.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker cp mycontainer:/var/log/mylog.log $(pwd)/logs/mylog.log
tail -f $(pwd)/logs/mylog.log
```